# java RestAssured: get() method with URL having "%2B" (plus symbol) in it

Tags: java, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I am hitting one URL having a plus symbol in it. A sample of the URL is given below:

```
https://api.digitalvault.cloud/<someText>/<someText>/samples?v=2.1&<someText>&startTime=2018-06-14T19:54:34%2b08:00&endTime=2018-06-14T01:54:34%2b08:00.
```

But it is not taking %2b symbol which is for Plus sign. Below is my code:

```
RestAssured.given()
    .config(RestAssured.config().sslConfig(new SSLConfig().relaxedHTTPSValidation()))
    .header("Authorization", Authorization).header(HeaderParameter1, HeaderParameterValue1)
    .header(HeaderParameter2, HeaderParameterValue2).get(URI);
```

Where URI is the actual url.

Could someone please suggest the way to handle this?

Comment: Please add what error you're facing

Comment: I am getting 400 bad request as response. When I set 'urlEncodingEnabled(false)', I am getting below exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 102

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
```

Example:

```
String url = "https://api.digitalvault.cloud/<someText>/<someText>/samples?v=2.1&<someText>&startTime=2018-06-14T19:54:34%2b08:00&endTime=2018-06-14T01:54:34%2b08:00";
System.out.println("Before ENCODING: "+url);
String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
System.out.println("After ENCODING: "+result);
```